# Insert multiple rows using prepared statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, postgresql, bulkinsert

I have an array of objects with each having multiple attributes. For example:

```
var obj = [{a : '1', b : '2'},{a : '3', b : '4'}];
```

To match the order sequence of the database table, I am generating a new array with the required sequence for bulk insertion.

```
var bulkInsert = function(arrData){
    var orderedData = [];
    arrData.forEach(function(obj){
        orderedData.push(obj.b + ',' + obj.a);
    });
    return orderedData;
};
```

Now, I want to bulk insert the output array of objects into the postgres table:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO sometable(b, a) VALUES" +
    " ($1, $2)", [orderedData], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(err, client, done);
        }
    });
```

However, this throws an error:

```
error fetching client from pool { [error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2]
```

The serial version works fine, if each case of insertion is iterated over a loop, but it will be slow for larger array..

Comment: `[orderedData]` should be `orderedData`, because that value is already an array. Otherwise, it takes 1 variable instead of 2 expected, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the square brackets from the array. It is already an array you don't need them

Comment: I get this error now: `error fetching client from pool { [error: bind message supplies 4 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2]`

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameters as a two size array. In order to insert two rows at the same time. Try repeat the following query two times :

```
client.query("INSERT INTO sometable(b, a) VALUES" + " ($1, $2)", [1,2], function (err, result) { if (err) { return handleError(err, client, done); } });

client.query("INSERT INTO sometable(b, a) VALUES" + " ($1, $2)", [3,4], function (err, result) { if (err) { return handleError(err, client, done); } });
```